Why is the speed graph of a survey flight a square wave?
Today, December 11, 2024 around 15:00 LT, there was an accident involving a Piper PA-31-350 Chieftain in Victoria, Texas, at the intersection of Zac Lentz Parkway (Texas 463) and Mockingbird Ln. The pilot was the only occupant of the plane and was injured. Four people in vehicles were injured, one critically. The plane was destroyed.
The flight tracking for flight N818BR on FlightAware shows the speed rising and falling. My question is why would this survey flight traveling back and forth show speed changes in a square wave pattern rather than something more sinusoidal (-ish)?
The second image shows the wind speed, gusts and direction from the National Weather Service at Victoria (KVCT) for the time period.



Welcome to aviation.stackexchange.com

The chart shows ground speed.  They're flying at approximately constant airspeed with an approximately constant wind (magnitude and direction).
The square wave depicts the up-wind and down-wind legs nicely.  You would expect a sinusoidal shape if they were flying in a circle.

I played the graph over time using the controls provided and sure enough. during NW flight the speed is at the lowest (the valleys of the wave) and SW flight has the higher speed (the peaks). I don't know why I didn't do that earlier. Just looking at the still image I expect the lows to be during the turns.

From a generic data analysis point of view I immediately wanted to see the heading on the same plot as the speed (and altitude).  I'd also want the wind data plotted on the same timescale (X axis).  It's a shame when all the information is in front of you, but presented in separate graphs - plotting the raw data yourself can be very instructive

I initially wondered if the survey equipment needs to run at a certain groundspeed, but your observation shows that can't be the case.   Good sleuthing !

Just out of curiosity - how do they know the ground speed at all? Is it something sent by the transponder? Do they have a theoretical value calculated by knowing the exact wind speed and direction at the moment - and adding the vector to the plane true speed/direction?

@Mykola I would imagine it's derived from GPS data, simply calculating based on the distance and time between updates.

@Mykola Definitely from GNSS, most likely GPS but possibly also other satellite constellations. For more advanced aircraft the FMS can use even more types of sources. They will be put together with the previous time-steps using Kalman filtering or a similar technique, better not just by differentiating the raw values from each source.

@VladimirFГероямслава, Cadence - Under GPS I meant from any constellation, not just GPS. My question was more about how the data is received by the FlightAware? I thought the transponder is quite simple on such planes, and only sends basic information, not the ground speed which is irrelevant in many cases, and to send the data it must be connected to a sat-nav device, an airspeed sensor would not do. Plus, the Piper in question is old, so, until retrofitted, does not have a sat nav integrated with transponder. I should probably ask a separate question.

@Mykola I actually believe the data is collected by ground based flight following radar.  As you mention, a transponder just squawks an ID (Mode A) and barometric altitude (Mode C).  The position and ground speed is measured by radar.  Radar is good at measuring a bearing (direction from the radar station) and radius (distance from the radar station), but not altitude -- which is why the transponder sends out altitude.  All of this technology predates GPS and other SATNAV technologies.

@Mykola These sites mostly receive data from ADSB. These are not that basic anymore and are connected to the source of position. Also, Transponders with mode S are becoming much more common than those simple mode C and are often obligatory in many airspaces. No need for a radar, an ADSB receiver network is sufficient.

@RobMcDonald I don't think those are collected by radars - I am pretty sure it is ADSB most of the time - I think, most of it collected by the network of volunteers who install a receiver connected to the Internet in exchange for access to the service or just for fun. The radars might be used by airports - but not the web services that the question quotes. Anyway, I asked a separate question and had an answer already, but thank you all for answering.
